# A component that acts like a buffer incase of power outage?

Tags: power, batteries, pc, outlet

I've had a few self inflicted power outages when too many appliances are connected at once, I got a blue screen on my PC as I had another power outage while booting, I've managed to fix this however I wonder if there can be other issues related to sudden power cut-off.

Is there such a thing as a power outage buffer? Something you can install in the outlet with a battery of sorts that supplies electricity for another minute or so until power is back on again?

I've scoured the internet and have to yet to find anything reasonable, maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing?

Comment: Try searching for UPS (uninterruptible power supply).

Comment: Well stop overloading! Every appliance has a nameplate stating amps or watts. You've reset that circuit enough times to know the number on the handle. **Don't exceed it**.  If you want more than that, for Pete's sake, adding additional branch circuits is *trivial work* for an electrician - the hardest part of the job is drywall and paint.   Just have one throw in a bunch of extra branch circuits, and never trip again!

Answer (score 1):

The device you need is called an [Uninterruptible Power Supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

What do you consider "Reasonable"?

Since you're only looking to ride through short interruptions, you don't need lots of battery capacity.  If you can find one with relatively short runtime that should save some money.

Comment: Well I don't really need anything powerful at all, something that can power a small bedside alarm clock or average desktop computer for a minute or so. I've even thought about buying a powerbank with a normal power outlet but I'm not sure what alternative would be the cheapest.

Comment: ROFL.  A UPS is how it is done, because that is what the UPS was designed for.  There is a significant difference between *a small bedside alarm clock* and *average desktop computer*.  You are overloading your circuit because you are drawing too much power, so as Monica says **Don't exceed it**.  That is the cheapest!